# Threading in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I just started with Threading in Python3. Is there any good tutorial/website that has a nice tutorial on how to work around with the threading module? By nice I mean it shouldn't be either too simple or too difficult to understand who is doing threading in python for the first time.

Comment: why don't use google yourself "python threading tutorial"? At least the first three or four provides provide reasonable information and examples. Python 2 code examples should work as well..where is the problem? Do you need everything spoon-ready?

Comment: I googled that, but it always came up with some very simple tutorials! That's why I had to turn to stackoverflow to get the exact right answer.

Comment: in that case please edit the question to include what you have already found, why you are thinking that they are simple and exactly for which level you are looking for. That will help you to get better answers. And also there are general concepts regarding thread which are not any language specific. Are you familiar with them? Have you done thread programming in other language?

Comment: @taskinoor thanks for the advice, will follow this advice from now on :) I've done a bit of threading in Java. And on google, most of the tutorials are for thread module and not about thrading. That's why I had to resort to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly unrelated, but since you're starting python 3, you should check out [Dive Into Python 3](http://diveintopython3.org/), if you haven't already.
There's also a whole heap of Python learning resources in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111857/what-did-you-use-to-teach-yourself-python). You'll probably be able to find what you're looking for in one of the referenced sites.

Answer (score 0):

I had to google for quite some time before I could find a good intro tutorial, these were the best i found:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/, basic but informative, and it uses a simple but realistic enough example (a url fetcher)

http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-threads-synchronization-locks-rlocks-semaphores-conditions-events-and-queues/, more detailed treatment of synchronisation, building on a similar url fetcher example, but still shorter than the one suggested above.